# Cosa significa "prospettare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> La tua sensibilità ti portava a **prospettare** ogni conflitto, anche il più banale e fortuito, come una colpa di cui soffrivi esasperandone i toni, l’umiliazione e lo sconforto.

Potreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di  "prospettare" in questa frase? Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prospettare) ho trovato che questo verbo significa

> Sottoporre alla considerazione o all’attenzione altrui, esporre, presentare e sim.

Tuttavia, a me non sembra che questo sia il senso nel brano sopra citato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La *Cronaca familiare* di Pratolini fu pubblicata nel 1947. Ecco per esteso la voce **prospettare** dello Zingarelli del 1948:

> a. [= verbo attivo] *prospectare. Stare a vedere, Guardare innanzi a sé. | *La palazzata di Messina prospettava il mare e la costa calabrese.* | neol. Dimostrare; Mettere in prospetto, mostra, Mostrare. | *le circostanze, la situazione delle cose* | *l'ipotesi*, Affacciare.

Quindi, all'epoca, il primo significato era quello etimologico di “guardare in avanti qualcosa”, detto sia letteralmente di un oggetto esposto per esempio al mare o a un certo punto cardinale, sia come qui di una persona che anticipa, cerca di prevedere, prefigura i conflitti (senza, a mio avviso, che sia ancora presente il senso, all'epoca considerato solo un neologismo, di mostrarli a qualcun altro).

Answer (score 0):

Se seguiamo il significato di *prospettare* nel senso di “presentare”, possiamo pensare che qui l’autore intenda dire che la sensibilità della persona di cui si parla la portava non solo a considerare (dentro di sé) ogni conflitto come una colpa, ma anche a mostrare tale considerazione con atteggiamenti evidenti agli altri («esasperandone i toni, l’umiliazione e lo sconforto»).